# Date compare like strtotime in C#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Have big problem I don´t know how to compare date in C# like PHP.
I want to convert this code in to C#:

```
$now = strtotime ("now");
$then = strtotime ("$date");
$difference = $now - $then ;
$num = ($difference/86400)/7;
$weeks = intval($num);
```

Which function should I use?
[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.aspx) can´t find a matching function like `strtotime`.

Please help me to convert the code to C#.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code converter at all. Please read [FAQ]

Comment: Use `DateTime.Now` to get current time. Minus operator (`-`) is overloaded and will yield you a `TimeSpan` object.

Comment: ps: `strtotime`, nice and verbose name. How happy I am to be a .net dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(yourDateTime);

var then = dt.ToString("HH:mm"); 

// here you can do rest of the calculations
```

basically

```
dt.ToString("HH:mm");  // 24 hour clock  
dt.ToString("hh:mm tt"); // 12 hour clock
```

Hope it will give you better understanding

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for something like below:

```
        DateTime sDateTimeNow = DateTime.Now;//Gets the date time from the server now
        DateTime sIn30Seconds = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30);//Gets date time and adds 30 Seconds
        DateTime sIn30Hours = DateTime.Now.AddHours(30);//Gets date time and adds 30 hours
        DateTime sIn30Days = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);//Gets date time and adds 30 days

        double dTotalDays = (sIn30Days - sDateTimeNow).TotalDays;
        double dTotalHours = (sIn30Hours - sDateTimeNow).TotalHours;
        double dTotalSeconds = (sIn30Seconds - sDateTimeNow).TotalSeconds;
```

Comment: BossRoss and Microtechie Thank you for the help. I think i know how i will solve it :)